# Strip away all HTML tags and formatting (RegEx)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have RSS feed that I want to modify on fly,  all I need is the text (and linefeeds) so everything else must be removed (  All images, styles, links )

How can I do this easily with ASP.NET c#

Comment: What are you cleaning up? The XML itself that comes from the RSS feed? Or just the HTML content of an individual feed entry?

Comment: Cleaning just HTML  (Description field of RSS) with a few IMG links

Comment: In that case I'll stand by my answer below :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regex cannot parse XML. Do not use regex to parse XML. Do not pass Go. Do not collect £200.

You need a proper XML parser. Load the RSS into an [XMLDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx), then use [innerText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.innertext.aspx) to get only text content.

Note that even when you've extracted the description content from RSS, it can contain active HTML. That is:

```
<description> &lt;em&gt;Fish&lt;/em&gt; &amp;amp; chips </description>
```

can, when parsed properly as XML then read as text give you either the literal string:

```
<em>Fish</em> &amp; chips
```

or, the markup:

> *Fish* & chips

The fun thing about RSS is that you don't really know which is right. In RSS 2.0 it is explicitly HTML markup (the second case); in other versions it's not specified. Generally you should assume that descriptions *can* contain entity-encoded HTML tags, and if you want to further strip those from the final text you'll need a second parsing step.

(Unfortunately, since this is legacy HTML and not XML it's harder to parse; a regex will be even more useless than it is for parsing XML. There isn't a built-in HTML parser in .NET, but there are third-party libraries such as the [HTML Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex).)

Comment: The regex culture war rages on!

Answer (score 0):

```
string pattern = @"<(.|\n)*?>";
return Regex.Replace(htmlString, pattern, string.Empty);
```

Comment: Fails for attributes with ‘>’ in value, comments, PIs, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful - you don't want to assume that the html you receive is well formed:

```
public static string ClearHTMLTagsFromString(string htmlString)
{
    string regEx = @"\<[^\<\>]*\>";
    string tagless = Regex.Replace(htmlString, regEx, string.Empty);

    // remove rogue leftovers
    tagless = tagless.Replace("<", string.Empty).Replace(">", string.Empty);

    return tagless;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did this in JavaScript for a project in much the same way as above:

```
var thisText = '';
thisText = document.getElementById('textToStrip').value;
var re = new RegExp('<(.|\\n)*?>', 'igm');
thisText = thisText.replace(re, '');
```